# How to set destination endpoint for OPShub to online endpoint

Tags: opshub

I downloaded the free version of the OpsHub so that I can migrate my work item types on TFS 2013 VS cloud.  but the downloaded version of the application that downloaded does not match the screen shot from the download site and when I select "select endpoint destination"  it does not give me an option to select an online location to migrate my current WIT files.  I am trying to migrate my current work items that I have built on tfs 2013 to tfs 2015 online.
THe image for the app on the download site says
1 provide endpoint details
a)team foundation server endpoint
b)visual studio online endpoint

and the app that I downloaded says.
1 provide endpoint details
a)source endpoint
b)Destination endpoint

thx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask] a question. Also, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

With free OVSMU migration utility version, only migration from TFS to online VSTS migration is possible. We regret the inconvenience regarding the image upload gallery page and accordingly we will change. On the end points, during "Providing end point details", there will be re-direction on to manage end point details and from there you can select the online VSTS option.
Thanks
Team OpsHub

Comment: so the commercial version of the app will allow me to migrate my current WIT files to the VS cloud and they will work the same way as they are today on TFS 2013?  I have custom work orders for Bugs, features, requirements and Change requests.   Is there a limit on how many work items I am allowed or able to download?

Comment: Yes, commercial version of OVSMU will allow you to migrate WorkItem, Test Entity and Version Control data to VSTS (VSO). There is no limitation in number of changesets/revisions/projects in the commercial version and custom work item and custom fields are supported as well.